Trying to iterate through JSON data to match user input
I have JSON data that I'm trying to iterate over until the key reaches 'teamName' and the value reaches the team the user inputted. Here's a small section of the JSON data that includes 2 teams:
{'body': [{'conference': 'American Football Conference',
           'conferenceAbv': 'AFC',
           'currentStreak': {'length': '0', 'result': ''},
           'division': 'East',
           'espnLogo1': 'https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/buf.png',
           'loss': '0',
           'nflComLogo1': 'https://res.cloudinary.com/nflleague/image/private/f_auto/league/giphcy6ie9mxbnldntsf',
           'pa': '0',
           'pf': '0',
           'teamAbv': 'BUF',
           'teamCity': 'Buffalo',
           'teamID': '4',
           'teamName': 'Bills',
           'teamStats': {'Defense': {'defTD': '3',
                                     'defensiveInterceptions': '18',
                                     'fumbles': '20',
                                     'fumblesLost': '10',
                                     'fumblesRecovered': '19',
                                     'passDeflections': '79',
                                     'passingTDAllowed': '18',
                                     'passingYardsAllowed': '3342',
                                     'qbHits': '117',
                                     'rushingTDAllowed': '14',
                                     'rushingYardsAllowed': '1880',
                                     'sacks': '54',
                                     'soloTackles': '719',
                                     'tfl': '86',
                                     'totalTackles': '1054'},
                         'Kicking': {'fgAttempts': '29',
                                     'fgMade': '24',
                                     'fgYds': '0',
                                     'kickYards': '0',
                                     'xpAttempts': '50',
                                     'xpMade': '49'},
                         'Passing': {'int': '18',
                                     'passAttempts': '579',
                                     'passCompletions': '385',
                                     'passTD': '29',
                                     'passYds': '4306'},
                         'Punting': {'puntTouchBacks': '3',
                                     'puntYds': '2334',
                                     'punts': '51',
                                     'puntsin20': '24'},
                         'Receiving': {'recTD': '29',
                                       'recYds': '4306',
                                       'receptions': '385',
                                       'targets': '545'},
                         'Rushing': {'carries': '512',
                                     'rushTD': '22',
                                     'rushYds': '2212'}},
           'tie': '0',
           'wins': '0'},
          {'conference': 'American Football Conference',
           'conferenceAbv': 'AFC',
           'currentStreak': {'length': '0', 'result': ''},
           'division': 'East',
           'espnLogo1': 'https://a.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=/i/teamlogos/nfl/500/mia.png',
           'loss': '0',
           'nflComLogo1': 'https://res.cloudinary.com/nflleague/image/private/f_auto/league/lits6p8ycthy9to70bnt',
           'pa': '0',
           'pf': '0',
           'teamAbv': 'MIA',
           'teamCity': 'Miami',
           'teamID': '20',
           'teamName': 'Dolphins',
           'teamStats': {'Defense': {'defTD': '4',
                                     'defensiveInterceptions': '15',
                                     'fumbles': '24',
                                     'fumblesLost': '10',
                                     'fumblesRecovered': '25',
                                     'passDeflections': '81',
                                     'passingTDAllowed': '27',
                                     'passingYardsAllowed': '3761',
                                     'qbHits': '140',
                                     'rushingTDAllowed': '15',
                                     'rushingYardsAllowed': '1650',
                                     'sacks': '56',
                                     'soloTackles': '711',
                                     'tfl': '79',
                                     'totalTackles': '1088'},
                         'Kicking': {'fgAttempts': '28',
                                     'fgMade': '24',
                                     'fgYds': '0',
                                     'kickYards': '0',
                                     'xpAttempts': '59',
                                     'xpMade': '58'},
                         'Passing': {'int': '15',
                                     'passAttempts': '566',
                                     'passCompletions': '393',
                                     'passTD': '30',
                                     'passYds': '4698'},
                         'Punting': {'puntTouchBacks': '3',
                                     'puntYds': '2424',
                                     'punts': '53',
                                     'puntsin20': '20'},
                         'Receiving': {'recTD': '30',
                                       'recYds': '4698',
                                       'receptions': '393',
                                       'targets': '549'},
                         'Rushing': {'carries': '456',
                                     'rushTD': '27',
                                     'rushYds': '2308'}},
           'tie': '0',
           'wins': '0'},

Here's what I've tried so far:
data = response.json()

userinput_team = input('Enter the team name')
userteam = str(userinput_team)

def defense(i):
    for key in data["body"][i]:
        value = data["body"][i][key]
        if key == 'teamName' and value == userteam:
            userdefense = data['body'][i]['teamStats']['Defense']
            print(f"Here are the defensive stats for the {value}:\n{userdefense}")
            return
        else:
            return defense(i+1)
        
        
defense(0)

Without the else statement if I input Bills for userteam, since i is already 0 the code works fine and the output is:
Here are the defensive stats for the Bills:
{'fumblesLost': '10', 'defTD': '3', 'fumbles': '20', 'fumblesRecovered': '19', 'soloTackles': '719', 'qbHits': '117', 'passingTDAllowed': '18', 'passDeflections': '79', 'passingYardsAllowed': '3342', 'totalTackles': '1054', 'defensiveInterceptions': '18', 'tfl': '86', 'rushingYardsAllowed': '1880', 'sacks': '54', 'rushingTDAllowed': '14'}

The problem is iterating through the data and stopping once the key reaches 'teamName' and the value reaches the team the user inputted. I figured with the else statement that the function would call itself if 'teamName' and userteam weren't found in the first index 0 and would just increment by 1 until they were found but all I get is IndexError: list index out of range and I'm not sure what to do.
I know I can just do something like:

data = response.json()

userinput_team = input('Enter the team name')
userteam = str(userinput_team)

Bills = 0
Dolphins = 1

userdefense_Bills = data['body'][Bills]['teamStats']['Defense']
userdefense_Dolphins = data['body'][Dolphins]['teamStats']['Defense']

if userteam == 'Bills':
    print(userdefense_Bills)
elif userteam == 'Dolphins':
    print(userdefense_Dolphins)
else:
    print('Team not found')

but this just seems counterintuitive considering the full JSON data consists of 32 total teams. I'm new to Python so I don't know if I'm missing some small detail. I've searched for similar questions but they're either in a different language or only on one level JSON.

Since you just need the first match, you can do this in a single expression using next():
userinput_team = 'Bills'

team_defense = next(
    (
        item['teamStats']['Defense'] 
        for item in data['body'] 
        if item['teamName'] == userinput_team
    ), 
    None. # <- this can be any default value you want for unknown team
)

Which will give you
{'defTD': '3',
 'defensiveInterceptions': '18',
 'fumbles': '20',
 'fumblesLost': '10',
 'fumblesRecovered': '19',
 'passDeflections': '79',
 'passingTDAllowed': '18',
 'passingYardsAllowed': '3342',
 'qbHits': '117',
 'rushingTDAllowed': '14',
 'rushingYardsAllowed': '1880',
 'sacks': '54',
 'soloTackles': '719',
 'tfl': '86',
 'totalTackles': '1054'}

if the team is found, otherwise None.

Accepted as this response is simple yet concise, thank you!

I believe you are trying to find the teamStats by the teamName.
I think something like below would work
data = response.json()

userinput_team = input('Enter the team name: \n')
userteam = str(userinput_team)

def defense():
    realData = data['body']
    for key in realData:
        if key['teamName'] == userteam: 
            userdefense = key['teamStats']['Defense']
            print(f"Here are the defensive stats for the {userteam}:\n{userdefense}")
            return
    print('No Data Found')
    
defense()

Since you are already looping I don't think you need that parameter in defense function.

I would prefer you use the get word in python dict to avoid key error and filter to match any matching name
For example:
def get_defensive_stats(data, userteam):
    # filter to find the team with the matching name
    teams = list(filter(lambda team: team.get('teamName') == userteam, data.get('body', [])))
    
    #any team was found and return its defensive stats
    if teams:
        return teams[0].get('teamStats', {}).get('Defense', {})
    else:
        return {}


The get word and filter function make the code much cleaner, thank you!

Based on your last code snippet, you are trying to retrieve the 'Defense' dictionary given a team name.
You can do something like this:
team_name = 'Bills'

defense = None
for team_info in data['body']:
    if team_info['teamName'] == team_name:
        defense = team_info['teamStats']['Defense']
        break

if defense is not None:
    print(defense)
else:
    print('Team not found')

